# Quick jump to a specific line of a file

Tags: find-file, point

After opening a `.txt` file with Emacs, when the point is at the line

```
/folder/subfolder/file.xml:435
```

How can I fast jump to line 435 of the above mentioned file?

What I tried:

`dired-at-point` and `find-file-at-point`

Comment: I'm not sure how to automatically jump there (it shouldn't be super hard to make a command to parse the file:line and automatically jump).  Use `M-g M-g` or `M-x goto-line` to jump to a line once the file is open.

Comment: I like @Tobias's answer, but depending on your use case you might want to look at `compilation-mode` and related commands like `previous-error` and `next-error`. Emacs has built-in support for handling various kinds of output that includes file names and line numbers, for compilation, grep, etc.

Comment: Many of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139970/open-a-file-at-line-with-filenameline-syntax take a stab at doing something along these lines, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can add this functionality to `find-file-at-point` with the following elisp snippet in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Please be aware that this method does not take into account that

`/folder/subfolder/file.xml:435`

inclusive the sub-string `:435` is a valid file name.

```el
(defun find-file-at-point-goto-line (ret)
  "Ignore RET and jump to line number given in `ffap-string-at-point'."
  (when (and
     (stringp ffap-string-at-point)
     (string-match ":\\([0-9]+\\)\\'" ffap-string-at-point))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line (string-to-number (match-string 1 ffap-string-at-point))))
  ret)

(advice-add 'find-file-at-point :filter-return #'find-file-at-point-goto-line)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you added a trailing colon to each line like so:

```
/folder/subfolder/file.xml:435:
```

Then enabling `M-x compilation-minor-mode` will have the desired outcome, such that you can type `RET` or use mouse-1 to visit the specified file at the specified line.

The trailing colon is needed because an error message is expected.  In this case the error message (following the new colon) is an empty string; but the separator is still required.

And as commented by @glucas, you can then also use `previous-error` and `next-error`, etc.

Comment: n.b. If you're comfortable with elisp you could likely write a custom entry for `compilation-error-regexp-alist` which would process the existing syntax, unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use the go-to line function in emacs. below is its brief help doc:

goto-line is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.

It is bound to s-l, M-g g, M-g M-g,   
.

(goto-line LINE &optional BUFFER)

Comment: THANK YOU, it is simple as that I don't have any idea why the emacs help forum makes things this much complicated when the question and expected answer are really simple, *Question:* how to jump to a line, *Answer:* use `M-g g` or `M-g M-g`

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on org-mode, you can open links of the sort

`[[file:/folder/subfolder/file.xml::435]]` with `C-c C-o` so with a few changes to the text in your example it's easy to open that link.

Maybe you can't edit the text or don't want to use org-mode so you could implement your own function. I'd still have a look at org mode (specifically `org-open-file`) to see how line number jumping is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

[Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)'s `helm-find-files` does this  out-of-the-box, if you are a helm user, you probably already have bound it to <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In my init files, I create a keymap I call `personal-map` and I bind it to `C-\` (I did this before `C-\` was used to select the input mode).  I then bind `goto-line` to `C-g` in the `personal-map` (along with other bindings) so I can do `C-\ C-g` and it prompts me for the line to go to.

If I was to do it now, I would use the other chord keys that are now rather standard on keyboards today such as the right option modifier can be set to `alt` or the right command key (Mac) can be set to `hyper`.  Then (for example) `(global-set-key (kbd "H-g") #'goto-line)` to map `goto-line` to `hyper lowercase g`.